Is my NEO M8N GPS design true?
I have always used GPS breakout cards until now. Now I want to use the same modules in another card that I have produced more professionally. I have obtained such a drawing with the drawings I found in a few places. However, I am not completely sure about its accuracy. That is why I wanted to ask if the design will work this way. Also, if you have a suggestion or something I should add, I would be very happy if you could write it.


CR1220 is a non-rechargeable battery. If you feed this battery with voltage it will probably burn..

U4 is backward ... also, it should really have a D designator, not a U ... U5 should be C5, same for U6

@jsotola I noticed that the designators were wrong, I think it was due to easyeda, but I forgot to change it. Thanks for reminding me. As for the U4 issue, I saw this in a few places, here is a visual I took from sparkfun's schematic.  https://i.postimg.cc/Bv1r8jTf/image.png

now I understand ... the connection to V_BCKP is unclear in the schematic diagram

Yes, exactly, is there any other mistake you see?
